# A thorny IIS deadlock caused by Autofac

Tags: iis, deadlock, autofac

I am a Autofac user, now face a very headache problem. I have been asked this question by Email Alex and Travis, and got their reply, here, thank them for their help.
To thoroughly check this problem, I accepted the recommendations of Travis, published  the details here.

**My Email:**

> We use Autofac 2.6.3.862 in a mvc3 project .
>
> Now we come to the IIS deadlock problem is serious, the server often
>   hanging, we have used the Microsoft Debug Diagnostics Tool to do the
>   analysis (leads to enclose the analysis report ), initially suspected
>   to be a lock in LifetimeScope
>
> I have read your article, but for some technical details are vague to
>   me. Most of our Register() component is SingleInstance, so when
>   Resolve() I doesn't use a a child lifetime scope like using (var scope
>   = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
>
> , do not know whether this is the reasons of deadlock.

**Debug Diagnostics analysis report**

```
The following threads in 
w3wp.exe__hg__PID__3904__Date__03_07_2013__Time_11_01_07AM__974__Manual Dump.dmp are waiting to enter a .NET Lock which thread 39 is currently holding    
( 26 34 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 )    
16.67% of threads blocked    

======================================================================================

Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at 0x0e758a00 owned by thread 26 in w3wp.exe__hg__PID__3904__Date__03_07_2013__Time_11_01_07AM__974__Manual Dump.dmp 

Impact of this lock    
1.85% of threads blocked

(Threads 39)

The following functions are trying to enter this critical section

clr!UnsafeEEEnterCriticalSection+1c    

The following module(s) are involved with this critical section

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

======================================================================================

Thread 26 - System ID 7628
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   2013/3/7 10:44:15 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.218 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.343 




This thread is waiting to enter a .NET Lock which thread 39 is currently holding



.NET Call Stack



Function 
System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(System.Object, Boolean ByRef) 
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object, Boolean ByRef) 
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(Autofac.IComponentContext, Autofac.Core.Service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Object ByRef) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(Autofac.IComponentContext, Autofac.Core.Service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Autofac.IComponentContext) 
Tunynet.DIContainer.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]() 
Spacebuilder.Common.ProfileRepository..cctor() 
Spacebuilder.Common.ProfileRepository..ctor() 
Spacebuilder.Common.UserProfileService..ctor() 
Spacebuilder.Common.User.get_Profile() 
ASP._Page_Themes_Channel_Default_Views_FindUser__QuickSearch_cshtml.Execute() 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
Tunynet.UI.ThemedWebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase) 
Tunynet.UI.ThemedRazorView.RenderView(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Object) 
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter) 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c.b__19() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.String) 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClass6+<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass8`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].b__7(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End() 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() 
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(System.Action) 
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet    
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+100    
kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+e0    
clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+56    
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+4d    
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+17d    
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+60    
clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+106    
clr!CLREvent::Wait+19    
clr!AwareLock::EnterEpilogHelper+a8    
clr!AwareLock::EnterEpilog+42    
clr!AwareLock::Enter+5f    
clr!AwareLock::Contention+228    
clr!JITutil_MonReliableContention+e8    
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)    
clr!CallDescrWorker+33    
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+8e    
clr!DispatchCallBody+20    
clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+75    
clr!DispatchCallNoEH+53    
clr!MethodTable::RunClassInitEx+f1    
clr!MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing+53e    
clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+f1    
clr!PreStubWorker+12c    
0x00f80842    
clr!MethodTable::GetRestoredSlot+2a    
clr!MethodDesc::GetMethodEntryPoint+4e    
clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+51d    
clr!PreStubWorker+15d    
0x00f80842    
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()    
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Push(System.__Canon)    
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase)    
System.RuntimeType+ActivatorCacheEntry..ctor(System.Type, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal, Boolean)    
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter)    
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1<System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutedContext>)    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.String)    
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)    
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClass6+<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()    
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()    
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(System.Action)    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)    
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)    
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)    
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)    
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)    
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)    
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)    
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)    
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+5b    
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::DoWork+250    
webengine4!RequestDoWork+2da    
webengine4!CMgdEngHttpModule::OnExecuteRequestHandler+1a    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+128    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+305    
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+28    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoStateRequestExecuteHandler+36    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoWork+d7    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ContinueNotificationLoop+1f    
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ProcessIndicateCompletion+1f    
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::IndicateCompletion+75    
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::IndicateCompletion+3d    
webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+24    
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)    
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)    
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)    
clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+10    
clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+8c    
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+f0    
clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+c0    
0x00f98c20    
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+5b    
webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+36    
clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+195    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::NewWorkerThreadStart+20b    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+3d1    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4b    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b 


=========================================================================

Thread 39 - System ID 4176
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   2013/3/7 10:44:21 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.140 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.109 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



.NET Call Stack



Function 
Spacebuilder.Common.ProfileRepository..ctor() 
Spacebuilder.Common.UserProfileService..ctor() 
Spacebuilder.Common.UserSearcher..ctor(System.String, System.String, Boolean, Int32) 
Spacebuilder.Environments.Starter.b__54(Autofac.IComponentContext) 
Autofac.RegistrationExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass10`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__f(Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0() 
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(System.Guid, System.Func`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(Autofac.Core.ISharingLifetimeScope, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource+<>c__DisplayClass4+<>c__DisplayClass6.b__1(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration) 
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext() 
System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource+<>c__DisplayClass4.b__0(Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(Autofac.Core.ISharingLifetimeScope, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(Autofac.IComponentContext, Autofac.Core.Service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Object ByRef) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(Autofac.IComponentContext, Autofac.Core.Service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Autofac.IComponentContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Autofac.IComponentContext) 
Tunynet.DIContainer.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]() 
Spacebuilder.Search.SearcherFactory.GetSearcher(System.String) 
Spacebuilder.Common.FindUserController._InterestedWithAll(Int32, Int32, System.String) 
DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, System.Object[]) 
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, System.Object[]) 
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass15+<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass15+<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass15+<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.String) 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClass6+<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass8`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].b__7(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End() 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() 
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(System.Action) 
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32) 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet    
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+13e    
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+150    
clr!UnsafeEEEnterCriticalSection+1c    
clr!CrstBase::Enter+1ad    
clr!ListLockEntry::FinishDeadlockAwareEnter+25    
clr!ListLockEntry::LockHolder::DeadlockAwareAcquire+28    
clr!MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing+4c2    
clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+f1    
clr!PreStubWorker+12c    
0x00f80842    
clr!PreStubWorker+165    
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()    
System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)    
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)    
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Push(System.__Canon)    
clr!JIT_Stelem_Ref+25    
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Push(System.__Canon)
```

**Alex Reply:**

> This does sound like a tricky one. What is the DIContainer class doing
>   and do you have any components registered as InstancePerHttpRequest,
>   or InstancePerLifetimeScope? There also seems to be some Quartz jobs
>   in the background too, how are they interacting with the container?

**Travis Reply:**

> A very quick look at the stack trace indicates you may have some
>   long-running operations or locks happening in the
>   Spacebuilder.Environments.Starter,
>   Spacebuilder.Common.UserSearcher.ctor,
>   Spacebuilder.UserProfileService.ctor, or
>   Spacebuilder.Common.ProfileRepository. What I'm seeing that's
>   interesting is that during a RESOLVE operation, when whatever
>   component it is gets RESOLVED, there's an internal REGISTER going on.
>   Without seeing the code, I can't tell you what's going on there, but
>   that thread - #39 - that's the stuff I'd look at.
>
> It looks like... A controller action is being invoked There's some
>   sort of lambda running over a closure (DynamicClass.lambda_method) -
>   something custom in your pipeline. SearcherFactory.GetSearcher
>   manually tries to resolve smoething. During the resolution in
>   GetSearcher, something is asking for a collection - like an
>   IEnumerable of services. A constructor parameter? Here's where it
>   gets weird: while resolving that IEnumerable, a new lifetime scope
>   is getting created and something appears to be getting registered in
>   it? The LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent call does do a lock to make
>   sure resolutions are thread-safe. The fact you're getting a deadlock
>   means two different threads are trying to resolve out of the same
>   lifetime scope (the container?) at the same time, which, in MVC, is
>   something to avoid - you probably wouldn't run into this, for example,
>   if you were resolving only out of the HttpRequest lifetime scope since
>   you'd only have that on one thread at a time. Alternatively, you may
>   be passing lifetime scopes around in the app for the purposes of doing
>   service location and that, too, can be a red flag.
>
> There is a wiki page on Concurrency that can also give you some
>   pointers: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Concurrency
>
> If that doesn't get you going in the direction you need, I recommend
>   posting to the discussion forum since, again, I'm not really able to
>   provide individual help necessarily in a timely fashion. That will get
>   other eyes on it and may get you help sooner. You'll want to include:
>   A description of the problem (like was in this email) but with more
>   detail about what you expect to happen (e.g., you're accessing a
>   controller action that does blah blah blah). The stack trace of the
>   blocking thread. The code around where things are getting blocked:
>   Your initial ContainerBuilder registrations to show how things are
>   getting registered. What's in those constructors and things that are
>   getting hung. That info will help folks more quickly root out the
>   problem. That's also the stuff you should be looking at with respect
>   to things getting locked

**My Supplementary question detail:**

The server often irregular hanging, the browser will stop responding suddenly util we use iisreset command to restart the server.  I'm not sure if a controller is called or some Quartz tasks triggered that time.

In Application_Start(), we use ContainerBuilder.Register() to regist many components in the same root lifetime scope. And These components may call each other.

Most them registered as SingleInstance, such as:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => new DefaultCacheService(new MemcachedCache())).As<ICacheService>().SingleInstance();
containerBuilder.Register(c => new QuartzTaskScheduler()).As<ITaskScheduler>().SingleInstance();
containerBuilder.Register(c => new UserService()).As<IUserService>().SingleInstance();
containerBuilder.Register(c => new UserSearcher("~/App_Data/IndexFiles/User")).As<ISearcher>().SingleInstance();
containerBuilder.Register(c => new TagSearcher("~/App_Data/IndexFiles/Tag")).As<ISearcher>().SingleInstance();
```

Only a few registered as InstancePerHttpRequest, these component initialization with each request related. such as:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => new FormsAuthenticationService()).As<IAuthenticationService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

We provide a class(DIContainer) includes some simple static methods for component resolve.  The static method is called when to resolve a component, such as in some Controller, Service, Repository(DAO) or Quartz tasks.

```
IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
DIContainer.RegisterContainer(container); 
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

public class DIContainer
{
   private static IContainer _container;

   public static void RegisterContainer(IContainer container)
   {
       _container = container;
   }

   public static TService Resolve<TService>()
   {
       return _container.Resolve<TService>();
   }
   ......
}
```

We use Lucene.Net for fulltext search service, each ISearcher corresponds to a type of search and an index directory. A ISearcher is resolved in SearcherFactory.GetSearcher() when needed.

```
public static ISearcher GetSearcher(string IndexPath)
{
   return DIContainer.Resolve<IEnumerable<ISearcher>>().Where(s => s.IndexPath.Equals(IndexPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So that is, but I still can not figure out the root reason. Wishing your help.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all the code and the stack trace but the first red flag is *"We provide a class(DIContainer) includes some simple static methods for component resolve."* <-- why don't you just use constructor injection as implemented by Autofac?  It will inject dependencies into Controllers, Services, ... just fine without resorting to `static` code passing around the container like this.  Why also would you keep resolving the `ISearcher` instances like that?  Aren't they a fixed set for the lifetime of the SearcherFactory and thus be injected into its constructor?

Comment: Given the thread holding the lock is in the `Spacebuilder.Common.ProfileRepository..ctor()`, `Spacebuilder.Common.UserProfileService..ctor()`, `Spacebuilder.Common.UserSearcher..ctor(System.String, System.String, Boolean, Int32)`, `Spacebuilder.Environments.Starter.b__54(Autofac.IComponentContext)` chain, we probably need to see that code (as mentioned in my original reply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve Method's inner implement is LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare，this method uses a thread lock. Check ProfileRepository's static constructor, maybe the constructor's thread lock and autofac's thread lock constitute a deadlock.